# Php vertically array merge

Tags: php, array-merge

This is my php arrays:

```
$array['title'] = array(0 => 'John', 1 => 'Wick');
$array['price'] = array(0 => '100$', 1 => '200$');
$array['count'] = array(0 => 88900, 1 => 92000);
```

I want to convert it like this:

```
$result[0] = array('title' => 'John', 'price' => '100$', 'count' => 88900);
$result[1] = array('title' => 'Wick', 'price' => '200$', 'count' => 92000);
```

I will do this a big data. How is the most effective solution?

Comment: Take a look at `array_column()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there a native way to do this but this works:
It is the most effective way? i'll let you benchmark it.

```
$array['title'] = array(0 => 'John', 1 => 'Wick');
$array['price'] = array(0 => '100$', 1 => '200$');
$array['count'] = array(0 => 88900, 1 => 92000);

foreach($array['title'] as $k=>$v){
   $result[$k]['title']=$v;
   $result[$k]['price']=$array['price'][$k];
   $result[$k]['count']=$array['count'][$k];
}

print_r($result);
```

> ```
> > Array (
> >     [0] => Array
> >         (
> >             [title] => John
> >             [price] => 100$
> >             [count] => 88900
> >         )
> > 
> >     [1] => Array
> >         (
> >             [title] => Wick
> >             [price] => 200$
> >             [count] => 92000
> >         )
> > 
> > )
> ```

Comment: This might fails or have unexpected results if you have empty keys or missmatching keys. Be sure to add some failsafe or @ if you feeel like it